# The Stack Overflow editor will not recognize comments properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

The following is the screenshot of an answer I had posted on Stack Overflow.[image: my answer]

What is to be noticed here is that the question is tagged [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), [vb.net-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2010), and [vb.net-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net-2013).
I executed the code in Visual Studio 2010 and posted it with comments (using `'`) for explanation, but at that time the comments were not recognized. Then I tried to comment them using a double slash (`//`) - that's shown in the image. But this is not the proper way of commenting in VB.NET - it'd be an error in Visual Studio.
Note that languages that use `//` for comments (C#, Java, C++) are not tagged here.

Link to my answer: [Creating a SQL Server database for the first time at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032171/creating-a-sql-server-database-for-the-first-time-at-run-time/25032383#25032383)

Proof that comments are recognized based on tags:

This comment will not be recognized

> [image: Vb code with C++ tag]

The comment is recognized

> [image: Vb.net code with vb.net tag]

Comment: The problem is not with one tag, it is because of the cobination of the Sql tag AND the VB tag which have both prettify hints. On a code block only one can exist and because prettify don't want to choose it fallsback to default. It can be easy solved by adding the language hint as I did on your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to manually specify which language you want it to be highlighted as, for example using lang-vb. Currently the tags on that question conflict with each other and cause it to revert to default, which means Prettify will try to infer what language it is.

See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: but all tags in this particular question wont support commenting with double slash `//`

Comment: Adding `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` before the code block does indeed fix it.

Comment: @Sujith The tags don't matter. They're ignored completely because they conflict with each other (sql vs vb).

Comment: Fixed it in this revision: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25032383/2

Comment: @ animuson : comments are recognized based on tags i will attach proof for this to my question soon

Comment: Yes, @Sujith, we know. animuson is saying, the tags are ignored in **that question, specifically**, because the tags that would trigger proper syntax highlighting (sql and vb) conflict with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reviews, now i got the problem i will suggest a solution in next post, keep it in mind while doing modification. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267579/introduce-language-specifier-to-avoid-conflict-with-tags